# Vue + Jest mocking global method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I'm working on a project that has a method defined in the script tag of the `index.html` file. For some reason, that causes Jest to fail when it runs.

`index.html`

```
<script>
var getCookie = function(cookieVal) { return cookieVal; }
</script>
```

To fix this, I've tried defining the 'getCookie' variable inside of Jest globals like:

`package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
      "getCookie": "someString"
    }
}
```

This does define `getCookie`, but when I run my tests I get this error:

> Error in data(): "TypeError: getCookie is not a function"

which makes sense, but I'm not sure how I can define it as a function in the `globals` object.

How can I mock my `getCookie` function in Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the [Jest docs indicate that `globals` cannot contain functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object), I verified that global functions could still be defined with a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) or [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
{
  jest: {
    globals: {
      getCookie() { return 'someCookie' },  // function expression
      getCookie: () => 'someCookie',        // arrow function
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) that sets `global.getCookie`:

```js
// package.json
{
  jest: {
    setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js']
  }
}

// jest.setup.js
global.getCookie = () => 'someCookie'
```